# Problema ao tentar excluir com delphi 5 uma dll feita em c# utilizando COM

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-5

Possuo uma DLL que utilizo para realizar assinatura digital de PDF's criada em c# (AssinaturaDigitalPdf.dll), ela por sua vez utiliza uma dll que manipula arquivos PDF (itextsharp.dll), eu carrego ela no Delphi e executo assinaturas sem problemas.

Eu embuti essas dlls no meu .EXE (utilizei arquivo .res para tanto), e eu tenho como objetivo extrair elas em runtime quando necessário, chamar as rotinas e em seguida exclui-las. Consegui fazer isso sem problemas, porem no momento da exclusão, eu deleto primeiro a "itextsharp.dll" que vai sem problemas e na sequencia tento deletar a "AssinaturaDigitalPdf.dll" o que me retorna erro 5: Acesso Negado.

Caso eu somente carregue a dll e não chame a rotina "AssinarPdf" eu consigo deletar o arquivo sem problemas.

Simplifiquei ao máximo o código, deixando apenas um "return = true" na DLL e continuo não conseguindo deletar, segue os códigos simplificados e com problema:

DLL:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace AssinarPdfCom
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("CE805AD4-511E-4E63-A37F-9FF6C97D664B")]
    public class AssinaPdf 
    {
        [DllExport]
        public static bool AssinarPdf(string CaminhoPdfEntrada, string CaminhoPdfSaida)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Classe responsável pela chamda DLL delphi:

```
unit uAssinaPdf;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  DB, StdCtrls, SDEngine, FileCtrl, Dialogs;

type
  TAssinarPdfFunc = function (pdfPathIn, pdfPathOut: String): Boolean; stdcall;

type

  TAssinaPdf = class(TObject)
  private
    dllHandle: HWND;
  public
    function AssinarPdf(pdfPathIn, pdfPathOut: String): Boolean;
    constructor Create; overload;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

function TAssinaPdf.AssinarPdf(pdfPathIn, pdfPathOut: String): Boolean;
var
  funcAssinaPdf: TAssinarPdfFunc;
begin
  @funcAssinaPdf := GetProcAddress(dllHandle, 'AssinarPdf');
  if @funcAssinaPdf = nil then
  begin
    result := False;
    exit;
  end;

  result := funcAssinaPdf(pdfPathIn, pdfPathOut);
  funcAssinaPdf := nil;
end;

constructor TAssinaPdf.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;

  dllHandle :=  LoadLibrary('c:\temp\AssinaturaDigitalPdf.dll');
end;

destructor TAssinaPdf.Destroy;
var
  hMod: HMODULE;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
  FreeLibrary(dllHandle);
  dllHandle := 0;
  hMod :=  GetModuleHandle('AssinaturaDigitalPdf.dll');
  FreeLibrary(hMod);

  if FileExists('c:\temp\itextsharp.dll') then
    if not DeleteFile('c:\temp\itextsharp.dll') then
      RaiseLastWin32Error; //aqui deleta normalmente
  if FileExists('c:\temp\AssinaturaDigitalPdf.dll') then
    if not DeleteFile('c:\temp\AssinaturaDigitalPdf.dll') then
      RaiseLastWin32Error; //aqui gera erro.

end;


end.
```

Evento do botão que chama as rotinas:

```
procedure TfrmTeste.actAssinarDocumentoAnexadoExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
  pathIn, pathOut: String;
  AssinaPdf: TAssinaPdf;
begin
  inherited;

  pathIn := 'c:\in\teste.pdf';
  pathOut := 'c:\out\teste.pdf';

  AssinaPdf := TAssinaPdf.Create;
  try

    if not AssinaPdf.AssinarPdf(pathIn, pathOut) then
      ShowMessage('falha');

  finally
    FreeAndNil(AssinaPdf);
  end;

end;
```

O problema não é permissão de pasta, pois a primeira DLL é deletada sem problemas, e não consigo encontrar alguma referência que possa estar travando a deleção.

Obs: Não consigo deletar a DLL nem manualmente em quanto o programa estiver aberto.

Comment: O seu problema continua ou Já resolveu ?